# rxtxSerial librxtx-java Ubuntu

Tags: java, serial-port, ubuntu-12.04

I am getting the following error when I try to run my Java application:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path
>   thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1878)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
>           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1087)
>           at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.(CommPortIdentifier.java:123)
>           at gqueak.GSqueak.connect(GSqueak.java:29)
>           at gsqueak.GSqueak.main(GSqueak.java:67)

I have installed **librxtx-java** like so:

> sudo apt-get install librxtx-java

My **/etc/enviroment** is:

> PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
>   CLASSPATH="/usr/share/java/:/usr/share/java/RXTXcomm.jar:/usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial.so:."
>   JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle:/usr/share/java/RXTXcomm.jar:/usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial.so:."

The **RXTXComm.jar** has been added to my netbeans Libraries and **-Djava library path="/usr/lib/jni/"** has been added to my VM Options within Netbeans.

I copied **/usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial.so** to **/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64**

I'm lost now as to what to do about to chew he keyboard.

Ubuntu 13.04
java version "1.7.0_25" (Oracle)
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

Thanks,

Comment: Its working now but not sure how. One thing to note is that you need to add your user to Dialout group if you want to connect to the /dev/ttyUSB0.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked out to add the VM option `-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni -cp /usr/share/java/RXTXcomm.jar:.` to the VM Options of Netbeans.